# How to work with OHLCV data across different time frames (5m, 15m, 30m, 1 hour, 4 hour, 1day) using Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, finance

Here is the code I have written as it currently stands:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from typing import List
import csv

def load_data(file_path: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Load data from a CSV file."""
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path, parse_dates=['time'], index_col='time')
    names = ['time','open','close','high','low','volume']
    return df

def clean_data(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Clean the data."""

    # Forward fill missing values in the 'time' column with hourly increments
    time_diff = df.index.to_series().diff()
    time_diff = time_diff.dt.total_seconds() / 3600  # Convert to hours
    time_diff = time_diff.fillna(0).cumsum()
    df.index = df.index + pd.to_timedelta(time_diff, unit='H')

    # Fill gaps in the price data
    df = df.resample('T').ffill()

    # Sort the DataFrame by the 'time' index
    df = df.sort_index()

    # Drop duplicate time slots, keeping the first occurrence
    df = df.drop_duplicates(keep='first')

    return df

def resample_data(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Resample the data to create new data points."""

    # Create new columns
    time_frames = ['5T', '15T', '30T', '60T', '240T', '1440T']  # in minutes
    new_columns = ['5_min', '15_min', '30_min', '1_hour', '4_hour', '1_day']

    # Select only the necessary columns for resampling
    columns_to_resample = ['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']

    # Create new columns with sub-columns for opening and closing prices
    for col in new_columns:
        df[col, 'open'] = pd.Series(dtype=float)
        df[col, 'close'] = pd.Series(dtype=float)

    # Assign resampled values to new columns and sub-columns
    for time_frame, col in zip(time_frames, new_columns):
        df_resampled = df[columns_to_resample].resample(time_frame).agg({
            'open': 'first',
            'high': 'max',
            'low': 'min',
            'close': 'last',
            'volume': 'sum'
        })

        # Apply linear interpolation to fill NaN values
        df_resampled = df_resampled.interpolate()

        # Assign resampled values to sub-columns
        df[col, 'open'] = df_resampled['open']
        df[col, 'close'] = df_resampled['close']

    # Check for NaN values
    nan_values = df.isna().sum()
    print(nan_values)

    # Return the modified DataFrame
    return df

# Load the data
file_path = r'C:\Users\Shadow\.cursor-tutor\projects\Machine Learning Modules\btcusd_ISO8601.csv'
df = load_data(file_path)

# Clean the data
df = clean_data(df)

# Resample the data
df = resample_data(df)

# Check the head of the DataFrame
print(df.head())

# Plot the data
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))
plt.plot(df['close'])
plt.title('Bitcoin Close price.', fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('Price in dollars.')
plt.savefig('bitcoin_close_price.png')
```

```
What am I missing?
```

The issue I am having is that the script as it stands is throwing up a lot of nan values in the output. The columns and tables are being created correctly but they are not populating with the correct extrapolated data.

Any help / debugging appreciated as I have hit a bit of a block and don't have more than a few months of Python experience to call upon.

many thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your post to contain an [mre].

Comment: We can't reproduce your issue without a example dataset.

Answer (score 0):

After some trawling through the pandas docs I managed to figure it out. Here is the completed script which now works with no nan values. Of course it could be totally off but having plotted a quick graph at the end to check the the overall shape of the data when compared to the same time frame of BTCUSD there is seemingly a good match. More testing required to get a proof I'm happy with but initial signs are good.

> '''

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from typing import List
import csv

## Load the data from the CSV file

def load_data(file_path: str) -> pd.DataFrame:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, parse_dates=['time'], index_col='time')
names = ['time','open','close','high','low','volume']

print(df)
return df
```

## Clean the data - Initial resample_data of the original data set, after using reindex and ffill functions to minimise missing data

de`enter code here`f clean_data(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:

## Clean the data

```
# complete time range from the start to the end of data at 1-minute intervals
full_time_range = pd.date_range(start=df.index.min(), end=df.index.max(), freq='1T')

# Reindex the DataFrame to have a row for each minute in the full time range
df = df.reindex(full_time_range)

# Forward fill to handle the missing data after reindexing
df.ffill(inplace=True)

# Aggregate the data as before
df = df.resample('1T').agg({
    'open': 'first',
    'high': 'max',
    'low': 'min',
    'close': 'last',
    'volume': 'sum'
})

# Sort the DataFrame by the 'time' index just in case
df = df.sort_index()

print('df.isna().sum()')
    
return df
print(df)
```

## Second stage of resampling through multi_index function to create new data points at 5, 15, 30, 60, 240, and 1440 minutes

## We also remove nan values using ffill and bfill

def resample_data(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:

```
# Define the time frames and corresponding new column names
time_frames = ['5T', '15T', '30T', '60T', '240T', '1440T']  # in minutes
new_columns = ['5_min', '15_min', '30_min', '1_hour', '4_hour', '1_day']
columns_to_resample = ['open', 'close', 'high', 'low', 'volume']

# Initialise a multi_Index for the new columns
tuples = [(col, sub_col) for col in new_columns for sub_col in columns_to_resample]
multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)
resampled_df = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index, columns=multi_index)

# Assigning resampled values to new columns and sub-columns
for time_frame, col in zip(time_frames, new_columns):
    df_resampled = df.resample(time_frame).agg({
        'open': 'first',
        'high': 'max',
        'low': 'min',
        'close': 'last',
        'volume': 'sum'
    })

    # Forward fill the resampled data to avoid NaN values
    df_resampled.ffill(inplace=True)

    print(df_resampled)
    
    # Assign resampled values to sub-columns
    for sub_col in columns_to_resample:
        resampled_df[(col, sub_col)] = df_resampled[sub_col]

# Combine the original df with the resampled_df
df_combined = pd.concat([df, resampled_df], axis=1)

# Reorder the columns to match the expected order
column_order = ['open', 'close', 'high', 'low', 'volume'] + list(resampled_df.columns)
df_combined = df_combined[column_order]

# Forward fill again to handle any NaN values after reindexing
df_combined.ffill(inplace=True)

# Back fill to complete the missing data
df_combined.bfill(inplace=True)

# Check for NaN values
nan_values = df_combined.isna().sum()
print(nan_values)

# Return the modified DataFrame
return df_combined
```

## Load the data

file_path = r'C:\Users\Shadow.cursor-tutor\projects\Machine Learning Modules\btcusd_ISO8601.csv'
df = load_data(file_path)

## Clean the data

df = clean_data(df)

## Resample the data

df = resample_data(df)

> '''